# Most Django-esque way of returning a common queries of a model

Tags: django, django-models, orm

My models are:

```
class DiscussionVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    path = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
```

I keep finding myself doing two common queries:

```
DiscussionVote.objects.filter(path=request.path, user=request.user).exists()
```

and

```
DiscussionVote.objects.filter(path=request.path).count()
```

I'm new to Django and not sure on the best route to creating a simple method to return these two common queries. What I'm thinking of is something along the lines of:

```
DiscussionVote.objects.get_vote_count(path) // to return a number
DiscussionVote.objects.has_voted(user, path) // to return a bool
```

Is this possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes @Sebastien is correct; you can also use a QuerySet (so you can chain things) and reuse more code in the long term. It might not fit your specific use-case as well but I find it better as project grows. Some pseudo-code here (not tested):

```
class DiscussionVoteQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def by_request(self, request):
        return self.filter(path=request.path)

    def by_user(self, user): 
        return self.filter(user=user)

class DiscussionVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    path = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)

    objects = DiscussionVoteQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Then you can do:

```
_count = DiscussionVote.objects.by_request(request).count()
_has_voted = DiscussionVote.objects.by_request(request).by_user(user).exists()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement custom managers in Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) which will allow you to achieve exactly this.